# Git: How to move repository in another repository without losing the history?

Tags: python, git, repository, move

I would like to move those two repositorys into the first one, how could I do this without losing the history of commits? Thanks! [This is what Im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeR2m.png)

I tried to search info about the issue but all I found is how to clone the repositorys, but with cloning I will loose the history if I just clone them into the new repo and then delete the old one =/ what I want to do is to move them somehow

Comment: A Git repository contains *commits*. It cannot contain another *repository*. You can either add a "gitlink"—an entry that goes into new commits that requests that Git clone *another* repository, via Git's "submodules" feature (which requires more than just the gitlink, but the gitlink is the part that makes things go)—or you can copy all the commits *from* the other repository. The history in any Git repository *is* the set of commits in the repository. That's all there is.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a local clone of the old repo. On this local, add the new repo as a new remote:

```
git remote add new-repo url-to-new-repo
```

Then, for local branches that you have, you can do

```
git push new-repo local-branch
```

And for branches that are in the old repo but you do not have locally:

```
git push new-repo old-repo/some-branch:refs/heads/some-branch
```

`old-repo` might be `origin`, of course.

Comment: Two days im trying to get this done and I cant , do you have a discord by a chance, if you are able to help me when you have some little free time ? Thanks! So far i went to there that i clone the items from the old repository and put them in the new one, but i cant find how to move them inside a a folder with the old repository name

Comment: Ahhhhh.... why do you want to do that? It's not like git cares on which repo something is committed/pushed.... that's not information that is persisted in commits. Anyway, if you would like to have the project inside any given directory since the beginning of the project, then you need to rewrite history and the tool for that job would be git filter-repo, to the best of my knowledge: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Answer (score 0):

My strategy in this case would be to use a `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories`. The merged repo will have two unrelated initial commits, which might seem weird when you look at the history, but the histories of the two repos will be contained in the merged repo, and you don't have to rewrite any history, just merge them.

Now, you said you want to move the files from one repo into a subdirectory. Do that first, before the merge. Then merge with unrelated histories, and push the results.

Here's a complete annotated recipe to do that:

```bash
# Start in a fresh sandbox - this is important, I'm assuming later you've done so,
# and it's easy to throw away and start fresh if anything goes wrong.
git clone URL/repo1.git
cd repo1
# Add a second remote in this sandbox, pointing to the second repo
git remote add r2 URL/repo2.git
git fetch r2
# Make and checkout a branch r2-main tracking the second remote's main
git checkout -b r2-main r2/main
# in this branch, move everything to folder repo2
mkdir repo2
git mv $(git ls-tree --name-only HEAD .) repo2
# commit (but don't push!)
git commit -m'Moving repo2 contents to folder repo2/ ahead of big merge'
# Go back to repo1's main - this local branch tracking it was created by the initial clone.
git checkout main
# And do the big merge
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories r2-main
# finally, if everything looks good, you can push to origin
git push
```

And now you should be all set the way you wanted!

Comment: Never mind this solution, use `git subtree` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75374353/3216427