# Merge git of 2 subdirectory into a newly created one of the parent directory

Tags: git, directory, repository

I have a project with the following structure:

```
.
└── maindir
    ├── subdir1
    └── subdir2
```

I started the project by setting a git repo in both `subdir1` and `subdir2`. The project has grown bigger and now I had to create a parent dir `maindir` and created a git repo in it too. However now it seems that the change made in `subdir1` and `subdir2` are not tracked by the git repo of `maindir`. Moreover, for simplicity reason, I want to merge all the commit info of all the git repos into one single git repo, namely the one of `maindir`. How can I do that?

**EDIT 1**

So I tried the answer of the link ([Git: Combining two independent repos to one without losing the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304870/git-combining-two-independent-repos-to-one-without-losing-the-history)) posted in the comment and got the following output. It seems to be more complicated than in the other SO question. What shall I do next?

```
$ git pull subdir1
remote: Enumerating objects: 58, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
remote: Total 58 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (58/58), 9.96 KiB | 231.00 KiB/s, done.
From standard_deviation
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint:
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint:
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

**Edit 2**

I am trying the `git filter-repo` package and trying to follow the commands but there are some details I do not understand. Therefore I anoted it to see if I understood it correctly

```
cd /path/to/subdir1 # now at level of subdir1
cd .. # now at level of maindir
mv subdir1 maindir # while at level of maindir, now renaming subdir1 to maindir, so there is maindir containing another maindir
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter subdir1/ # using the package
cd ../subdir2 # This is what I do not understand: why the `..`? because we should still be at the level of the first maindir. What am I not getting right?
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter subdir2/ # did not try from this point on
cd ../maindir # did not try
git remote add -f s2 ../subdir2 # did not try
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories s2/main # did not try
git remote remove s2 # did not try
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Combining two independent repos to one without losing the history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304870/git-combining-two-independent-repos-to-one-without-losing-the-history)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @evolutionxbox. The link you posted seems very interesting. However, the solution seems more complicated. I edited the question with the details.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt):

```bash
git init maindir
cd maindir

# At least 1 commit is required
# because `git subtree add` needs an existing branch
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"

git subtree add --prefix=subdir1 URL-for-repo1 master
git subtree add --prefix=subdir2 URL-for-repo2 master
```

For an existing repository instead of `git init` + `git commit` just do `git clone`.

Comment: Dang, so much simpler than the merge with unrelated histories I've been using. I wish I new about this a few weeks ago!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to reference `subdir1` and `subdir2` as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) inside `maindir`.

- move subdir repositories *outside* of maindir.
- add them back as submodules:

```
cd /path/to/maindir
mv subdir1 ..
mv subdir2 ..
git rm --cached subdir1
git rm --cached subdir2
git commit -m "remove nested Git repositories"

git submodule add https://url/subdir1/remote/repository subdir1
git submodule add https://url/subdir2/remote/repository subdir2
git commit -m "Reference subdir1 and subdir2 repository inside maindir"
git push
```

Note: the `git rm --cached` is not needed if you never git add'ed the nested git repositories in `maindir`. But you still need to move them out of the way.
And this assumes the subdir repositories have been pushed to their corresponding remote repositories (on GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, ...)

---

The other option, to avoid the "unrelated history", is to transform one of your subdir repository into `maindir`. And importing the second one.
This uses [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (which needs to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)).
And it follows [this gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/6161d90d1af8ebac6e560bcef548c1c3), using a [path shortcut](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_path_shortcuts) option:

> ```
> --to-subdirectory-filter <directory>
> ```
>
> Treat the project root as instead being under `<directory>`.
> Equivalent to using `--path-rename :<directory>/`.

So:

```bash
cd /path/to/subdir1
cd ..
mv subdir1 maindir
cd maindir
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter subdir1/
cd ../subdir2
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter subdir2/
cd ../maindir
git remote add -f s2 ../subdir2
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories s2/main
git remote remove s2
```

This time:

- you do not depend on remote repositories (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket...)
- you do not use submodules (which are references to repositories)
- meaning you end up with one single git repo (instead of one repository referencing two other repositories)

Comment: Thank you very much @VonC for your very extensive answer. I actually don't work with remote repositories currently. Everything is local on my computer. I think I would like to go to the `filter-repo` path, but so far could not make it work. What I did: I downloaded the file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/newren/git-filter-repo/main/git-filter-repo), named it `git-filter-repo.py` and wrote the following in my `.zshrc`: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/git-filter-repo.py` and then `source ~./zshrc`. But when I try `git filter-repo` command it doesnt work. Any idea about how I should proceed?

Comment: @ecjb It is best to follow the [installation instruction](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md). In particular, the "making sure to preserve its name (`git-filter-repo`, **with no extension**)" bit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @VonC. So I tried part of the commands line that you showed but there are some points I did not get right. I edited the question again accordingly. Do you see what am I missing?

Comment: @ecjb I missed a `cd maindir`. I have edited the answer.