# How to move GIT repository content to Monorepo repository with preserving commit history and branches?

Tags: git, monorepo, turborepo

I'm about to move my Next.js project repository to Turborepo, for visualization this is the folder structure:

```html
root
├── app/
│   └── my-app
├── packages/
│   ├── ui
│   └── hooks
├── node-modules
├── package.json
├── gitignore
├── turbo.json
└── README.md
```

I have cloned `my-app` repository from a remote URL, I want to move all commit history and branches into another repository that is located at the `root`, so when I'll what will be the best approach to achieve this result?

Comment: Try something from answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75348228/7976758).