Merging Multiple repo's into a seperate repo
I have to merge 130 different repos into a seperate one and make it so all of the other repos have a folder under the new repo where I want to merge them to.
Hi, I have the following code to merge a repository in an exsisting one, first I clone the New repo where I want to merge my code to with
git clone https://zbrobotics@dev.azure.com/automatisation/ZBautomatisation

then I go into the folder it creates and git bash -> run the following code:
git remote add 010707 https://zbrobotics@dev.azure.com/zbrobotics/Robotic%20Process%20Automation/_git/010707
git fetch 010707
git checkout -b 010707-merge 010707/dev
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories FETCH_HEAD
mkdir 010707
git ls-tree -z --name-only HEAD | xargs -0 -I {} git mv {} 010707
git commit -m "Merge 010707 repository into combined-repo"
git checkout dev
git merge 010707-merge --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin dev

After this is done I need the same code to run with different numbers but it starts nesting folders for some reason. I need to do this for over 130 Repo's and create a folder for every single 1.
I have tried different ways to get the folder structure fixed and I think that I fixed that but when I change the parameters of the block of code it still fails to adress the correct dev branch even when I try to switch it so the code currently only works once.

What did you try, where did you get stuck, how did it fail, and do you have a question? See [ask] then [edit] your question to provide all the missing information that'd allow us to help you (don't reply in a comment).

Did you consider [tag:git-submodules] or [tag:git-subtree]? git subtree seems to do exactly what you're doing manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75374353/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-subtree%5D+combine+repositories
